# Psexec run application on remote computer with admin credentials on a non-admin Windows login

Tags: c#, credentials, psexec

I know there are many PsExec questions out there, but I haven't found one yet that answers my specific case. Just like the title suggests, I have a program that sends to PsExec my admin credentials and uses them to open a program (i.e. calc.exe) on a remote machine. If I'm logged into Windows as an admin and pass PsExec my admin credentials, everything works fine. However, if I'm logged into Windows as a non-admin account and pass PsExec my admin credentials, it gives me an access denied to path error. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible? Here's my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Argruments = @"\\" + computer + " -u " + @"DOMAIN\" + username + " -p " + password + " -i -d -h " + "-accepteula " + processPath + " " + args;
info.FileName = PsExecPath();
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

Process.Start(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for my case here: [https://serverfault.com/questions/489822/psexec-is-not-connecting-to-machine-using-supplied-username-and-password/489845]

The reason it was failing was because "psexec still tries to access the ADMIN$ share with your local credentials, before executing your command as another user."

The solution is to cache your admin credentials on the remote machine before executing PsExec:

```
cmdkey.exe /add:MACHINE_NAME_HERE /user:MACHINE_NAME_HERE\Administrator /pass:PASSWORD_HERE 
psexec.exe \\MACHINE_NAME_HERE -i notepad
cmdkey.exe /delete:MACHINE_NAME_HERE
```